# SwiftUI & CoreData: delete list item and leading label

Tags: macos, swiftui, core-data, delete-row

I have a `SidebarView` within a `NavigationSplitView`. The `SidebarView` is a list of users with a leading label.

[image: app sidebar]

When I try to swipe-delete an user from that list an error is thrown in my `SideBarLabel` View: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.
It looks like that the label still exists after the user is deleted. How do I delete the complete row including label and user-object from CoreData?
I use this delete function but don't know how to manage to get rid of the users label:

my delete-func in `SidebarView`:

```
private func deleteSelectedUser(_ user: User){
    print(user)
  withAnimation {
          moc.delete(user)
      }
      
      do {
          try moc.save()

      } catch {
          let nsError = error as NSError
          fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
      }
}
```

my `SidebarView` code to create the list and swipe function:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct SidebarView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)])
var users: FetchedResults<User>

@Binding var selection: User.ID?

var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selection) {
        Text("Anwender")
            .font(.headline)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
         
        ForEach(users) { user in
            SidebarLabel(user: user)
                .swipeActions { Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                  deleteSelectedUser(user)
                    //print("swiped item is: \(user.name!)")
                }) {
                  Label("Remove User", systemImage: "trash")
                } }
...
```

with that I create the label and the user in the list:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SidebarLabel: View {

   //@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

   @ObservedObject var user: User

   var body: some View {
       Label(user.name!, systemImage: "person.circle")
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not wrap the label inside an `if let`? `if let name  = user.name {…}`. Or have a default value, `user.name ?? "deleted"`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: 1st approach sounds reasonable. But how to access the label of the selected user? Thanks. I don't understand how a default value can manage this.

Comment: 2nd approach is for inside the `Label`. If this is a synch issue between SwiftUI and Core Data you might not even see this happen in the ui

Comment: ah, ok. let me check this

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I used your 2nd approach and it works great (updated SidebarLabel): `Label(user.name != nil ? user.name! : "deleted User", systemImage: "person.circle")`.
It looks like a sync issue. But is this sync issue expected or does it happen due to bad coding anywhere else?

Comment: One thing you could experiment with is to pass only the name property to SidebarLabel so you don't have a coupling to the User object in that view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256582/discussion-between-jfs-and-joakim-danielson).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're hitting this is that your `delete` command is happening asynchronously within the `withAnimation` block, which doesn't block the rest of that method. So by the time the code hits `try moc.save()`, the object may not have actually been deleted. Then it's deleted from the context and not saved (until the next time you call `save()`) – so it might still appear in the fetched results, but any attempt to access it will fail.

Rather than putting the save in a `withAnimation` block, you could add an animation to the `@FetchRequest`, so that your delete method is cleaner:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
  // ...
  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)],
    animation: .default
  ) var users: FetchedResults<User>
  // ...etc...

  private func deleteSelectedUser(_ user: User){
    do {
      moc.delete(user)
      try moc.save()
    } catch {
      let nsError = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
  }
}
```

If you still find you're getting an error, you could be extra secure by checking whether the user has been deleted in your `SidebarLabel`:

```swift
struct SidebarLabel: View {
  @ObservedObject var user: User

  var body: some View {
    if !user.isDeleted {
      Label(user.name!, systemImage: "person.circle")
    }
  }
}
```