# While performing delete operation the app crashes showing this :Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x180803488)

Tags: core-data

I have a refactored data model with multiple attributes from (https://github.com/abdelrahmanTD/TaskToDo), those are:
Task:NSManagedObject:
id: UUID
name: String
complete: Bool//code take from
priorityNum: Int32//
date: Date
para: String
Now the delete function is performed in the view called MemoryPool but this error pops up in a different file Called TaskListView where the date is present.

Task Coredata

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

// Create Core Data class for Task entity
@objc(Task)
public class Task: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var complete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var priorityNum: Int32
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    @NSManaged public var para: String
}

extension Task: Identifiable {
    var priority: Priority {
        get {
            Priority(rawValue: Int(priorityNum)) ?? .normal
        }
        
        set {
            self.priorityNum = Int32(newValue.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

enum Priority: Int {
    case low = 0
    case normal = 1
    case high = 2
    
    var priorityType: String {
        switch rawValue {
            case Priority.low.rawValue: return "low"
            case Priority.normal.rawValue: return "normal"
            case Priority.high.rawValue: return "high"
            
            default: return ""
        }
    }
    
    // to set color for each type of priorities
    func priorityColor() -> Color {
        switch rawValue {
            case Priority.low.rawValue: return .green
            case Priority.normal.rawValue: return .orange
            case Priority.high.rawValue: return .red
            
            default: return .orange
        }
    }
}
```

MemoryPoolView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MemoryPoolView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Task.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.complete, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.priorityNum, ascending: false)
        ],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    @State private var showNewTask: Bool = false
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var selectedTask: Task?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(tasks.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.contains(searchText)}) { task in
                        TaskListRow(task: task)

                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
                }
                .listStyle(.sidebar)
                if tasks.count == 0 {
                    Image("no-data")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Memories")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showNewTask = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .opacity(self.tasks.count == 0 ? 0.5 : 1)
                        .disabled(self.tasks.count == 0)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: self.$searchText, placement: .automatic)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNewTask) {
            NewTaskView(isShow: self.$showNewTask)
                .offset(y:30)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteTask(index: IndexSet) -> Void {
        withAnimation {
            index.map { tasks[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError.localizedDescription), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }}

#Preview {
   MemoryPoolView()
}
```

TaskListRow

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskListRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext // to save the updates
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(task.name)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .strikethrough(task.complete, color: task.priority.priorityColor())
                .opacity(task.complete ? 0.5 : 1)
            
            Text(task.para)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.brown)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: task.date))//the thread breakpoint appears here
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 12)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .onReceive(self.task.objectWillChange) { _ in
                    if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
                        try? self.viewContext.save()
                    }
                }

    }
}

struct TaskListRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let testTask = Task(context: PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        testTask.id = UUID()
        testTask.name = "Test Task"
        testTask.complete = false
        testTask.priority = .normal
        testTask.para = "Before you can begin to determine what the composition of a particular paragraph will be, you must first decide on an argument and a working thesis statement for your paper. What is the most important idea that you are trying to convey to your reader? The information in each paragraph must be related to that idea. In other words, your paragraphs should remind your reader that there is a recurrent relationship between your thesis and the information in each paragraph. A working thesis functions like a seed from which your paper, and your ideas, will grow. The whole process is an organic one—a natural progression from a seed to a full-blown paper where there are direct, familial relationships between all of the ideas in the paper."
        testTask.date = Date()
        return TaskListRow(task: testTask)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 350, height: 200))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

When I delete the certain object it deletes object but the app crashes, what I was expecting is the app to not crash

Comment: Why do you have `.onReceive(self.task.objectWillChange)` in TaskListRow when there is no editing being done in that view? Maybe this is the cause of the crash?

Comment: It most propably happens because of some sync issues with the `TableListRow` View after delete tasks. @JoakimDanielson helped me once on a similar issue. Try to add an default value for the task.name in `TaskListRow` View: [stackoverflow.com/questions/77815392[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815392/swiftui-coredata-delete-list-item-and-leading-label)